# Как расшифровать tls пакет

Tags: шифрование, tls, пакет

Здравствуйте, скажите пожалуйста, как расшифровать tls пакет, а точнее `Encrypted Application Data`? Я знаю что его просто так не получится расшифровать как обычный какой нибудь base64, поэтому хотел уточнить алгоритм расшифровки, так как почитав про способ передачи tls пакетов, я вычитал что при соединении между клиентом и сервером пересылается какие-то промежуточные пакеты, в одном из которых есть как я понял "ключ", но я вот не могу понять какой это ключ и каким именно алгоритмом (aes, blowfish и т.д.) расшифровывать наш зашифрованный `Encrypted Application Data`(который ниже)?
:

```
0000   31 0a 4f ef 38 59 22 3a c2 97 7e 9c 5e 69 60 9a  1.O.8Y":..~.^i`.
0010   03 43 41 d6 eb 35 ee 05 96 37 a1 5b e4 e5 ec 40  .CA..5...7.[...@
0020   02 c8 85 aa 98 7e 60 5a 62 2c a6 37 cb fb ce 5a  .....~`Zb,.7...Z
0030   18 6a 5f 46 00 52 8d 17 90 bc 4e 92 d0 32 4a 76  .j_F.R....N..2Jv
0040   be 31 48 df 3e 4e c6 a8 fe 89 21 2b 8a 44 fe b9  .1H.>N....!+.D..
0050   9e 8a 15 39 57 9f 0a fe 0e e1 7b f6 31 0a a5 39  ...9W.....{.1..9
0060   dd ef 1f b0 df d0 3a 69 e2 0f f3 71 5e 90 d6 09  ......:i...q^...
0070   12 c3 a4 ba 19 bd d7 6a 81 3c 23 94 03 bd c0 13  .......j.<#.....
0080   b3 39 ab 76 7d 7c 69 9b 9e 84 81 0a e4 3b 60 71  .9.v}|i......;`q
0090   0a eb de da f8 31 b7 cf a6 5b 41 d7 a5 45 e1 09  .....1...[A..E..
00a0   fd c0 10 a9 87 c7 78 ea 86 65 1d 29 fc 77 be 34  ......x..e.).w.4
00b0   e5 52 2e 79 c2 33 ce 20 d2 e9 85 c0 5b a5 58 48  .R.y.3. ....[.XH
00c0   53 94 cc ba dd 82 23 6b 98 44 a5 f0 4a 3a 74 a0  S.....#k.D..J:t.
00d0   1f 4b 64 1c 24 b7 84 9c c7 15 e9 45 5d e9 08 d6  .Kd.$......E]...
00e0   6a 40 61 6c 1a 75 42 ca 73 79 23 f6 2b 8e 48 20  j@al.uB.sy#.+.H 
00f0   da 13 cd 89 48 45 a5 e9 90 07 e3 37 aa 64 ab 83  ....HE.....7.d..
0100   87 93 1c c4 3e af 19 8e 4b eb 88 63 85 30 94 24  ....>...K..c.0.$
0110   22 ec c2 a5 95 ce 37 c2 51 72 0e 8c fe 59 0d 32  ".....7.Qr...Y.2
0120   f5 a7 e6 07 e5 cb af ae 03 0c ab d7 10 38 55 83  .............8U.
0130   ff 3f 95 6e 0f 7e 7c 22 9c f5 09 b9 1d 1f de 7d  .?.n.~|".......}
0140   05 b3 e0 ab 39 f4 91 77 1e 1a b5                 ....9..w...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Имея одно только `Application Data` сообщение, вы ничего не расшифруете. Алгоритм генерации ключей происходит во время рукопожатия (`TLS-handshake`). По размеру сообщения можно строить догадки, какой шифр использовался, AES-CBC, AES-GCM, AES-CCM и т. д., но эта информация вам ничего не даст.

Даже если у вас будет полностью сохраненная TLS-сессия со всеми сообщениями, скорее всего вы не сможете ничего расшифровать, даже если у вас будут приватные ключи от сертификатов. Сейчас в основном используются наборы шифров со свойством `Perfect forward secrecy`, а это значит, что не имея алгоритма взлома схемы Диффи-Хеллмана трафик невозможно расшифровать, даже взломав сертификаты.

Если вам повезло, и там использовался набор шифров без `Perfect forward secrecy`, то получив приватный ключ от RSA сертификата вы сможете расшифровать весь трафик.